# Removing a div on all screen sizes greater than 480 px using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap and i want to show a div on or less than `480px` but it should be invisible on all screen sizes greater than `480px` how it can be done with media queries or any other techniques. Please help me getout from this problem.

```
 @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
        #hidetop{
            display:none;
        }
        #showtop{display:block; }
        .reduce-margin
        {
        margin-top:0px; 


}
}
```

Comment: can you post some code or any jsfiddle ? @user...

Comment: I have added media queries what i am using

Comment: but i want to hide this #hidetop div on all sizes greater than 480 px how will i write that through media query.

Answer (score 0):

In main css , Give display none for that div

```
#hidetop{display: none;}
```

Then use following code in your responsive.css

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {

#hidetop{display: block;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as below, add into your CSS. Via: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
.div {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .div {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below code hope will help you

```
#hidetop{
            display:none;
        }
@media (max-width:480px) {
    #hidetop {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

here is js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xf6gA/19/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use min-width. One less CSS rule.

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    #hidetop {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

And [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) is a good resource for learning the other things you can do with media queries. You can combine criteria, and use a not operator. You can even detect when a device is in landscape mode!